# Suitable Replacement for mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["variable"])?

Tags: php, mysql

I run a website which has various product pages, the data for which is called using:

```
$ProductDescription= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["ProductDescription"]);
```

Recently, this has stopped working - I'm assuming that my server has stopped allowing it due to a security vulnerability (the page works perfectly if the var $ProductDescription is just entered manually instead). So my question is simply what would be the best code to use to pull a variable from the URL? I've seen some vague suggestions about MySQLi, but I don't really know what that is or how to use it.

Comment: Learn PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements.

Comment: This might be caused by your version of PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

If you are on a newer version of PHP you might just need to try the mysqli_real_escape_string version of what you have above.

Comment: You can see some examples of how using prepared statements look here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use MySQLi and a prepared statement with placeholders, if your query is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE description='".$productDesctiption."'";
```

you can convert it to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE description=?";
```

then with mysqli you prepare the statement and execute it:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $ProductDescription);

$ProductDescription=$_GET["ProductDescription"];
$stmt->execute();

...retrieve your data...

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Have a look at this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).